# tweak regex to accept several of the pattern

Tags: regex

I validate my input if it passes both regex above. 
How can I tweak both regex so that it accepts a list ie (like on input2 and input3). Right now my regex only work on input1.

2 or higher:

```
^\d{2}\d*$
```

non 0:

```
^[1-9]\d*$
```

---

```
input1: 123
input2: 123, 456
input3: 123, 456, 789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the pattern you posted is equivalent to `^\d{2,}$`, which requires the number to have two or more *digits*. The regex for an integer greater than or equal to 2 is more like `^[+-]?0*([2-9]|[1-9]\d+)$`. From your description, it's not clear which of these you intended.

Either way, what you want to use is something like this:

```
^(<pattern>(,\s|$))+$`
```

So for your scenario, it would be something like:

```
^(\d{2,}(,\s|$))+$                #2 or more digits
^(0*([2-9]|[1-9]\d+)(,\s|$))+$    #positive integers >= 2
^(0*[1-9]\d*)(,\s|$))+$           #positive integers > 0
```

I'm not sure what flavor of regex you're using, but if your engine balks at the redundant use of `$` in the patterns above, you could try something like

```
^(<pattern>,\s)*<pattern>$
```

instead. Example:

```
^(\d{2,},\s)*\d{,2}$    #2 or more digits, simplified
```

Bear in mind that a better way to do this is usually to split the string on the comma + whitespace separator, which will give you an array of strings you can try to parse as integers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, here's what I'd recommend for your base regexes:

Two or more digits:

```
\d{2,}
```

One or more digits:

```
\d+
```

Now if you want either of them to match a comma-and-space separated list, you could use:

```
(?:\d{2,}(?:\s*,\s*)?)+
```

and

```
(?:\d+(?:\s*,\s*)?)+
```

respectively

Comment: This also runs into the catastrophic backtracking problem I described below Mark's answer. If the delimiters are fully optional, it's ambiguous where the captures begin and end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^[1-9]\d*(?:\s*,\s*[1-9]\d*)*$
```

`[1-9]\d*` matches one or more digits, the first of which cannot be zero.  If there are any more characters after the first number, they must comprise a comma optionally surrounded by whitespace -- `\s*,\s*` -- followed by another number.  And that repeats as many times as necessary.

You can be more strict about the format if you like.  For example, if the comma must follow immediately after the number and there must be exactly one space after the comma, you can use this:

```
^[1-9]\d*(?:, [1-9]\d*)*$
```

Comment: For the sake of validation, you could turn that first `*` into `+` so the string can't start with a comma. That would make an empty list fail to match, though.